# git push is not pushing the changes to the repository

Tags: git

I am new to git and trying to understand what its commands do, So for this i installed git in my windows system.

I made one of my folder as git repository, by running the command "git init". This created ".git" directory in that folder.

```
cd git-repo
git init
```

After that i tried to clone that repository, so for this i made a seperate folder and went inside that and ran the `"git clone ../git-repo"` command. This cloned the git-repo.

Now i did some changes in this cloned folder, and tried to commit it to the git-repo by using the commands :

```
git add .
git commit -m "test commit"
git push origin branch1
```

But the problem is that the pushed changes is not visible in the git-repo. 
Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever create a branch named `branch1`? By default, a freshly created repository only ever contains a `master` branch (and that only after you've made the first commit)...

Answer (score 1):

you are pushing to a none-bare repo. depending on your git version this (still) works, but with newer gits it will no longer work.

you should be pushing to a bare repo (that can function similar to a server in centralized version control) and then pull from there, i.e. make the transfer indirect.

read more about bare repos: http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html

Answer (score 1):

You just missed one option when you created the "remote" repository. Try the following

- move to the folder you want to use as remote git repository and issue the command: `git init --bare`. The `--bare` initialize the repository as a remote one, in which you can later push
- move to any folder you want to use as working (or local) repository and do the clone: `git clone /remote-repository`
- now you should be able to `push` and `pull`. Simply, `git push` should work.

My personal suggestion is to work with custom [remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), since when you clone a repository git will always create a remote called `origin` associated with the branch `master` and this may become confusing when you work on more repository.

Comment: owk now i tried this and i noticed that after pusing the commit to the bare repo i cant see the changed files in the repo, but when i clone it i can the new changes in the clone.

Comment: A `bare` repository does not show the files, at least it is not made to be navigated. I honestly don't know where you can look for the files on the server

Answer (score 0):

What is `branch1`? Maybe the original repo has `master` or someother branch checked out. You will have to `git checkout branch1` in the original repo to see those changes.

Comment: @himanshu - What git repo?  the one you are pushing from? You don't have to specify that. Just try doing `git push origin master`

Comment: Tried to do that but it filed, see logs below :  


`himanshu@DELL-PC ~/Desktop/git/test-clone3/git-repo (branch1)`  
`$ git push origin master`  
`error: src refspec master does not match any.`  
`error: failed to push some refs to`    `'c:/Users/himanshu/Desktop/git/git-repo'`