# Git error on committing new repository ([remote rejected] master )

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

I have a project I want to place on Git. I never had an issue with Git but for some reason it won't work for this project.
All my projects are on a shared network drive. First I created a new repository on the network drive then I cloned this repository on to my system. Then I copy the existing project in the Git/projectname folder. When I do a commit and try to select all added files I get an error message as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Only commit works fine but when I try to push I get another error message:

[image]

The error message after selecting all files:

```
    warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/chosen.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/css/select2.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tooltip.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.button.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.dialog.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.menu.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.resizable.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.selectable.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.slider.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.spinner.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.tabs.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.tooltip.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/jquery.noty.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottom.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomCenter.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/center.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/centerLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/centerRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/inline.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/top.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/topCenter.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/topLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/layouts/topRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/promise.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/noty/themes/default.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/select2.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Tool/Scripts/select2.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/EPPlus.3.1.3.3/EPPlus.3.1.3.3.nuspec.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/Select2.js.3.4.1.2/content/Content/css/select2.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/Select2.js.3.4.1.2/content/Scripts/select2.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/Select2.js.3.4.1.2/content/Scripts/select2.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/chosen.0.12.0/content/Content/chosen.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/chosen.jquery.0.12.0/content/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.2.0.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.2.0.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.2.0.3/jQuery.2.0.3.nuspec.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tooltip.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.button.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.dialog.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.menu.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.resizable.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.selectable.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.slider.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.spinner.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.tabs.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.tooltip.min.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.3.nuspec.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/jquery.noty.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottom.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomCenter.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/bottomRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/center.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/centerLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/centerRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/inline.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/top.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/topCenter.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/topLeft.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/layouts/topRight.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/promise.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/content/Scripts/noty/themes/default.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in packages/jquery.noty.2.1.0/jquery.noty.2.1.0.nuspec.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
DoneStage 303 files
```

Error message after push:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" master:master
Counting objects: 236, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 236 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master[K
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository[K
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent[K
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match[K
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to[K
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into[K
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you[K
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some[K
remote: error: other way.[K
remote: error: [K
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set[K
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.[K
To G:/eTemplate_tools
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:/eTemplate_tools'
Done
```

After I try the second push:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" master:master
Counting objects: 236, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 236 (delta 56), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/pack/pack-53d213811e38773414f34a05b02d1051e5609dc5.pack: Permission denied[K
remote: fatal: cannot store pack file[K
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To G:/eTemplate_tools
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:/eTemplate_tools'
Done
```

Comment: side note: personal recommendation: stop git from messing with your files and set `core.autocrlf` to `false`. others might disagree, but read about it.

Comment: where are you pushing to? you should not be pushing to non-bare repos. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260792/2536029

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll defiantly check it out!

Comment: @mnagel you might as well answer the question, because it looks like you've identified both of the issues, the first being that `core.autocrlf` is set to `true` but the file's being checked are Unix style, so Git is giving that warning, and the second issue being that the original poster is trying to push to a non-bare repo. There's a third issue, the original poster should not be trying to check in NuGet packages, let NuGet package restore manage dependencies, because Git is ill-suited for versioning binary files. I'll upvote your answer, by the way.

Comment: @Cupcake and everyone: done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here we go. There are three apparent issues with your git setup.

*Thanks to @Cupcake for pointing out the third one.*

From most important to least important:

- You try to push to a non-bare repository. This is not recommended and actually an error with recent git versions. You should push to a bare repo. For further information let me refer you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18260792/2536029
- You have set `core.autocrlf` to something other than `false`. This causes git to try to automatically convert line endings depending on the exact value of `core.autocrlf`, your environment, the files in question and previously applied conversions.

  Some argue that this is useful in scenarios where some contributors use windows and others use UNIX, but in my opinion it more often causes trouble because it unexpectedly changes your files in ways that are difficult to predict (especially for novices) and hard to track down/communicate as they easily get lost when discussing things via mail and/or other channels.

  `<rant>` git does not convert all code to python, even if I tell it that I like python the most. Likely it does not translate all comments to French, even if I use a French locale. It should leave my line endings intact... `</rant>`

  For information how to change `core.autocrlf` see https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings but keep in mind that github recommends something different than I do. So this is under discussion and your mileage might vary...
- NuGet seems to be some kind of package manager that downloads prepackaged (binary) data. You are committing this binary data. This is not a hard error but @Cupcake and I predict that you will not be happy on the long run.

  For small things like jQuery or bootstrap it is probably OK and will simplify deployment while not really burdening git, but git really does not like binary blobs and if you have lots of them or big binaries it will be become more and more noticeable, at some point it will be apparent and finally it will suck. It will not break, but it will suck and ruin your git experience.

  You should look into other ways to track the binaries. With NuGet it seems reasonable to run NuGet whereever you deploy/clone your repo, with binary media assets (e.g. in game development) the situation with git is even sadder.

Best Regards